# Confused with stack using a singly linked list

Tags: c, stack, singly-linked-list

This is what I've done so far, I'm pretty new at linked lists and stacks so they're kind of confusing to me, I'm trying to figure out how to do my isempty function, it is supposed to give me 1 if empty and 0 if not empty.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct stack node;
typedef struct stack *link;

struct stack
{
   int val;
  link next;
};

// Global top variable
link top = NULL;


void push(int n)
{
  link tmp;
  tmp = malloc(sizeof(node));

  tmp->val = n;
  tmp->next = top;
  top = tmp;
}

int pop()
{
  int val = top->val;
  link tmp = top;
  top = top->next;
  free(top);

  return val;
}

int isempty()
{

}


void printstack()
{
  link tmp = top;

  while (tmp != NULL)
  {
      printf("%2d ", tmp->val);
      tmp = tmp->next;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int x, i, j;
  printf("Enter an integer: ");
  scanf("%2d ", &x);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like you could simply use `if(top)`, since `top` will equal `NULL` when the stack is empty.

Comment: sorry, I'm not the best at this, so you're saying 'if ( top == NULL )' return your 1 value else return your 0 value, correct?

Comment: Correct, `int isempty(){return (top == NULL) ? 1 : 0;}` or simply `int isempty(){return (top == NULL);}`

Comment: Ah okay, thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Yeah, my bad. For `isempty()` my suggestion should have been `!top`, but I hope it helped anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it seems function pop has a typo

```
int pop()
{
  int val = top->val;
  link tmp = top;
  top = top->next;
  free(top);
  ^^^^^^^^^
  return val;
}
```

There must be `free( tmp )` instead of `free( top )`.

Also you should check whether the stack is empty inside the function.

I think it is better to define the function the following way

```
int pop( int *value )
{
    int success;

    if ( ( success = top != NULL ) )
    {
        *value = top->val;

        link tmp = top;
        top = top->next;
        free( tmp );
    }

    return success;
}
```

As for function `isempty` ` then its implementation is simple

```
int isempty()
{
    return top == NULL;
}
```